# AS400 JDBC driver problem in SpringBoot project

Tags: java, gradle, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I have a Spring Boot application that connects to multiple databases - Oracle, SQLServer, DB2, MySQL etc.

I import the requisite JDBC drivers via Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.22'
implementation ('com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8')
implementation group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '19.9.0.0'
implementation group: 'com.ibm.db2', name: 'jcc', version: '11.5.6.0'
```

and so forth. They all work fine.

I now have a requirement to connect to DB2 on an AS400 server. There are two potential drivers: one via DBConnect with a license, or the open source JT400 library. I am using the latter.

I added this dependency statement in the same build.gradle file:

```
implementation group: 'net.sf.jt400', name: 'jt400', version: '10.6'
```

Refreshing dependencies downloads the library as expected. I can even see it listed in the classpath declaration when starting the app:

```
[...]681a/jjwt-0.9.1.jar:/home/paul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.jt400/jt400/10.6/3f391a43632a93874dd3f544d7cb5a91b7a02380/jt400-10.6.jar:/home/paul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/...
```

If I attempt to connect to an AS400 URL, however, I get a "No suitable driver found" when attempting the connection.

I can debug into the application when the connection is attempted, and try `Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver")` and receive a class not found exception. If I open the referenced jar file, the named class exists as expected.

I built a small sample application with just this particular jar on the command line, and it executes perfectly (the response is expected, as I'm not pointing at an actual AS400 server yet).

```
paul@paul-adm-dev:~/$ java -cp .:/home/paul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.jt400/jt400/10.6/3f391a43632a93874dd3f544d7cb5a91b7a02380/jt400-10.6.jar AS400ConnectionExample 
java.sql.SQLException: The application requester cannot establish the connection. (Connection refused (Connection refused))
```

I tried changing the dependency to Compile and to the obsolete Runtime, to no avail. I even tried the import in other sub-projects that make up the overall application, but always with the same result.

I am stumped. What might cause this one single library to be not loaded?

Comment: Thinking it could be some sort of driver class conflict, I also tried my sample app with the DB2 jcc driver on the classpath, both before and after the AS400 library, and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Sigh.

This particular driver, in spite of its own documentation, does NOT auto-register with the SQL driver manager.

Adding `Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver")` in a static initializer in the component tasked with creating Connections solved the issue. No idea why it failed to do so in a debug session evaluation window, but at least now I know why this driver didn't 'just work' as the others do.

Comment: This should be reported as a bug to the jt400 project.